# How to scale the size of sprite dynamically in XNA + C#?

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection, sprite, 2d-games

I'm creating a 2D shooter and I would like to increase the size of certain enemies when collision occurs between that and a projectile object. 
I can scale the sprite in the code by just changing the float value below

```
enemyAnimation.Initialize(enemyTexture, Vector2.Zero, 47, 61, 8, 30, Color.White, **2f**, true);
```

I can then change that float to a variable, and update the variable when a collision occurs. The only problem is, that the enemy scale does change but only for newly spawned enemies and all of them. This was obvious but what I want to be able to do (if at all possible) is change the size of the enemy that the collision occurred with and only that enemy...

Any ideas on how I might go about doing this?

EDIT:

Okay, I am a little confused. I have created a float value called scaleSize in my Enemy class. Then in collision detection in my Game1.cs I am running a for loop to iterate through my list of enemy objects

```
// Projectile vs Enemy Collision
            for (int i = 0; i < projectiles.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < enemies.Count; j++)
                {
                    // Create the rectangles we need to determine if we collided with each other


                    // Determine if the two objects collided with each other
                    if (rectangle1.Intersects(rectangle2))
                    {

                        enemies[j].Health -= projectiles[i].Damage;
                        projectiles[i].Active = false;

                            *enemies[j].scaleSize += 1f;*
                    }
                }
            }
```

Now I realise scaleSize is not being initialized properly. But I am unsure of where I should change this. As above in the earlier code sample, the float value is changing the scale of the enemy but through the Animation class and if I change this, it changes for all enemies (afaik). 
I am sorry as I know this is very vague but I just can't wrap my head around where I should set the enemies scale size. creating it enemy class is fine but it is not referencing the actual scale of the enemy.

Comment: How are you keeping track of the location of the enemies, do you have a class that you can add more fields to or are you using an enumerable of Vectors?

Comment: I have an Enemy class with this information. If the enemy goes out of the screen or it collides with player or projectile object, it is killed off. position of enemy is stored here too. currently following Jon's advice and adding scale value to this class.

Comment: You can probably initialize your scale to 1 all the time, that would be a pretty safe assumption

Comment: @emartel thank you, but this is making the scale size static. I want it to be changeable in game. setting it as 1f is fine for the normal look but I would like to increase the size when a collision occurs.

Comment: @NoGimmicks you, you can keep it non-static... `protected float mScale = 1;` should work no problem

Comment: @emartel I have it set like this more or less, in my Enemy.cs but the problem I am having is that this does not reference the actual scale of the sprite and I am not sure how to manage this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the scale value in your Enemy class.  That way, each instance of your Enemy objects will have their own scale value.

If you do not have an Enemy class, you should create one.  You can also store the enemyTexture, and have each Enemy have their own appearance.

**Edit**

You most likely are not using the proper scale value in your Draw method.  Take an example Enemy class:

```
class Enemy
{       
   protected float Scale { get; set; }
   protected Texture2D Texture { get; set; }
   protected Vector2 Position { get; set; }

   public Enemy()
   { 
       Scale = 1f;
   }

   public void Hit()   
   {
       Scale = 2f;
   }

   public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
   {
        spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, Position, null, Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, Scale, SpriteEffects.None, 1);   
   }
}
```

Usage examples:

```
Enemy A = new Enemy();      
A.Hit();    
A.Draw(spriteBatch);
```

Comment: I have an enemy class, I will try that now. Thank you for your quick reply.

Comment: Hi Jon, I've edited my post with more information (as vague as it might be). any ideas?

Comment: Check my edit.  Try to follow the same model, and it should work.

Comment: Thank you Jon, I was unable to get it working this way. Most likely due to the way I have my classes set up. But this gave me insight on how to use the class effectively. I ended up just deleting the enemy and re-spawning an enemy, with larger scale, in the location where the other enemy object was deleted. Not as re-usable or efficient but does the job nonetheless.